# How to calculate a simple running total?

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is table: Customer

[image]

And this is table Transactions:

[image]

They are related by No.

I want the running total of Esaldo:

So:

```
Running total =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Transactions[ESaldo]),
FILTER(
ALL(
Transactions),
Transactions[Date] <= MAX(Transactions[Date])
)
)
```

This is wrong:

[image]

Due to the external filter (slicer).

So, this should do it:

```
Running total 2 =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Transactions[ESaldo]),
FILTER(
ALLEXCEPT(Transactions, Transactions[no]),
Transactions[Date] <= MAX(Transactions[Date])
)
)
```

If the `ALLEXCEPT` was meant to be understood... It should remove all the filters from Transactions, and preserve the filter in column No.

But it wasn't and thus the result is the same:

[image]

So, maybe... `ALLSELECTED`?

```
Running total 3 =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Transactions[ESaldo]),
ALLSELECTED(Transactions[no])
)
```

Nope:

[image]

**EDIT:
Here's the link to the pbix file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W5cnLtIBD9REYbr3VdhIZqTcCtxz62hp?usp=sharing**

Comment: Why your first result is wrong, it looks correct to me

Comment: Because on 15/05/2020 it should be:  505 195,60 €

Comment: so you want to ignore the slicer filter

Comment: No, I want to preserve it

Comment: you may see my edit above with a link to the pbix file

Answer (score 0):

Dear @nuno if i am not mistaken you might have already found the solution with this code

```
Running total 2 =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Transactions[ESaldo]),
FILTER(
ALLEXCEPT(Transactions, Transactions[no]),
Transactions[Date] <= MAX(Transactions[Date])
)
)
```

If you look closer you will see that from your prints runnig total 2 is actualy doing its calculation correctly by adding each invoice per row.

But the 166k that you see at the end is actually not suming the values above. It actually aplying the same measure to the entire table (another evaluation context) which is in fact correct to and is exacly the same as SUM(Transactions[ESaldo]) with no filters.

Nonetheless, given the nature of the example, this total is useless if your goal is to present as a table. you probably want the totals to be consistent.

Try the code below where i try to change the evaluation context inside calculate (sorry but the link above to pbix doesn't seem to work)

```
Running total 2 =
 CALCULATE(
  CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
    VALUES(Transactions[Date]),
      CALCULATE(
       SUM(Transactions[ESaldo])
      )
    )
  )
    
  FILTER(
   ALLEXCEPT(Transactions, Transactions[no]),
   Transactions[Date] <= MAX(Transactions[Date])
  )
 )
```

Does it work? it should change the context surrounding the date column and correct the total at the end

Comment: Actually, I managed to get it working with:
Running total 2 =
CALCULATE(
SUM(Transactions[ESaldo]),
FILTER(
ALLEXCEPT(Transactions, Transactions[Name]),
Transactions[Date] <= MAX(Transactions[Date])
)
)